# Unable to get google token in postman

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-api, postman, google-people-api

I'm developing an app that will need google's OAuth2.0. Initially, I was trying to test the webservice using postman. and below are the steps that I've followed.

1. In https://console.developers.google.com/, I've created a project.
2. Under Library I've enabled **Google People API**
3. In credentials, I've created one with https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback as redirect URL
4. I got the lient secret and client ID.

With the above details I'm trying to test the same in postman.

In post man I did the below steps.

1. Selected **OAuth2.0** under Authorization and clicked on **get new Access token**. This opened a new window and I entered the below details.
2. Auth URL : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
3. Access Token URL : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
4. Client ID : the one that I got from google console
5. Client Secret : the one that I got from google console
6. Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
7. Grant Type: Authorization Code.
   And when I click on request token, I'm redirected to accept the permission and to my surprise, the configuration details window (In postman), doesn't go off and display me a token. Below is a screenshot post I click on Request Token.[image]

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the imgur api. Did you solve it?

Comment: @A__ nope bro :(

Comment: I ended up restarting the application and getting it to spit out a token for me. Not sure what exactly the issue was though or how to replicate.